# VS 2017 always times out debugging an MVC Core website on IIS Express profile

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

On a plain vanilla, scaffolded ASP.NET Core MVC web app, with a `DbContext` registered in the DI container, whenever I hit F5 after 30-60 seconds, I get the error message:

> Unable to start program 'http://localhost:60175/'. Operation timed
>   out.

The home page in an index view, whose action gets all employees from a localhost SQL Server db. The project is already built, so the initial build for debug is quite quick, and doubtfully the cause of the delay.

If I run without debugging, I get the home page up in 30 - 40 seconds.

Just what is timing out, and can I set that timeout? Or is there anything else I can to to speed up this painfully slow debugging setup, compared to MVC 5, where the home page opens after only a few seconds.

Comment: Please note, there is no MVC6 (anymore) http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/

Comment: Since you are using a localdb I would assume it is the time it takes for the database to attach to the SQL Server.   Could you use an database on a sql server instead?

Comment: @KenTucker I'm not using `localdb`, I'm using, I quote, *a localhost SQL Server", i.e. MSSQL installed on the same machine. There could be no way to make the connection time quicker in my case except upgrade my PC.

Comment: @Tseng I know that full well, I was just comparing my current MVC 6 speed to what I used to have with all my MVC 5 apps.

Comment: It's hard to say whats causing it in your case, we don't know your setup, we don't know your configuration or code. What I can tell you is that I never experienced this issue. Did you increase the debugger verbosity via the appsettings.json? http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#built-in-logging-providers, i.e. by setting all values to `Trace` level?

Comment: @Tseng I have set all log levels to `Trace`, but the logging is performed by the web app,.and the error is not in that app. The error occurs in VS, which times out before it can connect to the web app, so my output window in a blank slate when I get the timeout error.

Comment: Are the delays also there when you run it from console via `dotnet run`? Sounds odd indeed

Comment: @Tseng It turns out the delays are not in the app itself, but in VS getting it started up, and hence timing out. Using `dotnet run` gives very little delay, but then how do I debug it?

Comment: Check `Properties/launchSettings.json` - how mane `profiles` you have? It must be two: one with commandName=IIS Express and other with commandName=Project. In VS your 'Run' button is a dropdown - select other profile there, not iis express. And run.

Comment: @Dmitry When I select the the Project profile VS bombs because it can't connect to the Remote Debugger. Even if I start the remote debugger before hitting the "Run" button. All I can do is start the remote debugger first, runt the app with `dotnet run` (i.e. leave VS out of the whole startup), and then use VS to attach to the `dotnet.exe` process.

Comment: @Tseng No, no delays with `dotnet run`, but only a small delay for "Run without debugging, effectively the same thing.

Comment: @ProfK it's strange. My VS2017 does not request for any remote debugger for local site. Installed side-by-side with VS 2015. Next step is reinstall :( , but VS 2017 RTM releases march 7 - may be wait and reinstall clean RTM....

Comment: @Dmitry VS2017 RC is an astounding beauty with everything but ASP.NET Core debugging. I truly believe the ASP.NET Core team has focused far too much on using the CLI interface on other platforms, their crowning glory, and sorely neglected properly integrating debugging with VS2017. I too believe that this area will still be below production standard even after RTM.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say if it is the same issue, but I had same symptoms when I was starting my current project.  In my case, I found I either had to:

- Turn off Browser Link; or
- Use a browser other than Chrome as the startup browser.

It wasn't until I selected Microsoft Edge as the browser in the debug button of the toolbar and it worked fine that I realised what it might be, and I disabled Browser Link.  It all starts up fine now.

If it is yet another issue, then best of luck.

Comment: I suspect BrowserLink as well, but it's true, VS 2017 is still so, so very RC, even with less than 2 weeks left to RTM..I foresee weekly updates to that RTM for at least 6 months.

Comment: Any updates on this issue for 2018 regarding lengthening .net Core (2.1) debug timeouts?