# What process must I attach to for debugging an MVC 6 wep app using the IIS Express profile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express, visual-studio-2017

I am desperately trying to achieve the supposedly very simple goal of debugging an MVC 6 (Core 1.1) web app in VS 2017 RC3. Normal debugging does not work, as VS always times out trying to attach to the program, as asked about in my [VS 2017 always times out debugging an MVC Core website on IIS Express profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42186361/8741) question. Now I am stuck with "Start without debugging", and trying to attach to whatever process is actually hosting my app.

The app type is a Console Application, which starts up the Kestrel host, yet this console app produces no `.exe` that I can find anywhere. Of course I have tried to attach to IIS Express, but using that, none of my breakpoints are ever hit. I believe in these scenarios, IIS EXpress merely acts as a proxy to the actual console app that is my MVC app, so maybe I should attach to the actual web app process, but what in hell's name is that process?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to attach to the dotnet.exe process. You may have multiple dotnet.exe (especially if you run a .NET Core project VS at the same time). Typically, when you press Ctrl+Shift+P in VS it would be the first dotnet.exe.

However, your symptoms look like your application is not actually starting at all and IIS Express cannot find the process. I would start from checking event log for IIS Express related events as IIS logs the process ID of the application it started and the failures if any.

A better way to debug this might be to skip IIS Express at all and start your application directly from command line with `dotnet run`. This way you will see output in the command line window. You can also print the process id from your Main method with:

```
Console.WriteLine("Process ID: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
```

so that it easy to figure out what process to attach to if you need it.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am slowly gaining some ground, but when I try to attach to the correct process, I get, `Unable to attach to the process. Visual Studio Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) failed to start.`

Comment: Are you debugging remotely?

Comment: No, I'm debugging to the `dotnet` process, but when I added an external tool command to start `MSVSMON.EXE`, and do that before attaching, my debugging finally works. Thank you, Pawel!

Comment: Glad you made it work but you shouldn't have to do that. Maybe try repairing VS?

Comment: I repaired it Sat night, when I first tried debugging, and it made no difference. Maybe it's my Windows updates that are quite behind, I've got the very latest, late Jan VS2017, but apparently there's a new update due in few days. I'll just throw the `dotnet run` and debugger start in a `.cmd` file, and all I have to do us run that an attach. No fuss. Maybe even map F5 to it. :-)